# Let $1< m,n \in \Bbb N$. The map $g: \Bbb Z_{m} \to \Bbb Z_{mk}$ given by $x \mapsto kx$ is a monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Let $1< m,n \in \Bbb N$. The map $g: \Bbb Z_{m} \to \Bbb Z_{mk}$ given by $x \mapsto kx$ is a monomorphism

Example from Hungerford's Algebra.

Clearly this is injective, but why is it a homomorphism? I don't see how to get a factor of $k$ for each equivalence class.

$g(\bar{x}\bar{x_{1}}) = g(\overline{xx_{1}}) = \overline{kxx_{1}}$ = ?

Comment: I'm guessing this is about the *additive groups* $Z_m$ and $Z_{mk}.$ Is that right?

Comment: It doesn't say...

Comment: Since it's not a ring homomorphism, I have to assume we're talking about groups, in which case your groups are generally written additively.  In this context, the fact it's a homomorphism is just the distributive property $k(x+y) = kx + ky,$ moved into the corresponding quotient group.  (note that the fact this map is well-defined is the only problem)

Comment: Yep, thank you for clearing this confusion of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x+y)=k(x+y)=kx+ky=g(x)+g(y)$.  I have switched to additive notation (you had actually sort of mixed the two, since in multiplicative it would be $g(xy)=(xy)^k=x^ky^k=g(x)g(y)$).

Answer (score 1):

$g(\bar{x}+\bar{x_{1}}) = g(\overline{x+x_{1}}) = \overline{k(x+x_{1}}) = \overline{kx} + \overline {kx_{1}} = g(\bar{x}) + g(\bar{x_{1}})$.